# curl: (55) Failed sending HTTP POST request

Tags: http, curl

I got the `curl: (55) Failed sending HTTP POST request` error while trying to make a POST call to a pingable URL.

```
$ curl -v POST \ 
  https://myhost.com/page \
  -H ': application/json' \
  -d '{
    "api_key": "1234"
}'
```

Answer (score 3):

- Revisit the request carefully.
- Make sure that all headers are in proper syntax (key: value)
- URL is properly enclosed in `''`
- All command flags are valid.

In my case, one of the request headers missed its key during copy from the clipboard.

```
$ curl -v POST \ 
  https://myhost.com/page \
  -H ': application/json' \ . <<----
  -d '{
    "api_key": "1234"
}'
```